# Нужны ли знаки препинания между приложением и именем собственным

Tags: приложение

Нужны ли запятые в предложении *Ученики 5 класса "А", Серова А., Карапетян Г, Васильев Е., стали победителями....*

Comment: Вариантов оформления такого предложения достаточно много, и они перечислены у Розенталя old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103 КАКОЙ ВЫБРАТЬ? А это зависит от структуры предложения в записи автора, и предложение это желательно видеть ПОЛНОСТЬЮ (а не фрагмент из него с многоточием в конце). В некоторых же случаях и контекст не помешает...

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике Розенталя в [этой главе (пункт 4)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103) есть следующие предложения:

> Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян.
> Славятся своими здравницами города-курорты Кисловодск, Железноводск, Ессентуки, Пятигорск.

В предложениях выше нет предупредительной интонации перед однородными (второе предложение может иметь такую интонацию), однако ваше предложение может иметь предупредительную интонацию перед перечислением однородных, если оно произносится на каком-нибудь мероприятии с награждением. Так что здесь возможны два варианта знаков в зависимости от произношения:

> Ученики 5 класса "А": Серова А., Карапетян Г, Васильев Е. – стали победителями.... (При наличии предупредительной интонации.)
> Ученики 5 класса "А" Серова А., Карапетян Г, Васильев Е. стали победителями.... (При отсутствии педупредительной интонации.)